# Connect UISwitch with event in other view controller

Tags: ios

i have 2 view controller the first one is main view controller and will run music when the view controller load and the other view controller is settings that content an UISwitch so what i want is when the user go to setting view controller and turn switch off then the music will stop in the main view
here is the code

main.h

```
#import<AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface main : UIViewController
{

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
BOOL didInitialize;
```

}

main.m

```
static BOOL didInitialize = NO;
if (didInitialize == YES)
return;
didInitialize = YES;
//Add Audio Sound to the current View Controller
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MLGBoxSoundTrack.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // -1 for looping forever

//    audioPlayer.volume = 0.5; // 0.0 - no volume; 1.0 full volume
//    NSLog(@"%f seconds played so far", audioPlayer.currentTime);
//    audioPlayer.currentTime = 5; // jump to the 10 second mark
//    [audioPlayer pause];
//    [audioPlayer stop]; // Does not reset currentTime; sending play resumes

if (audioPlayer == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"No Audio Player");
}
else
{
    [audioPlayer play];
}
//End Audio Sound
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use `NSNotificationCenter`](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/)

First view controller, add observer for switch notification, second view controller post notification when switch is switched.

Comment: There are plenty of resources available online, including the link I included with my answer.